# Wordpress https 'redirected you too many times.' error

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I am hosting a wordpress site on AWS and am transitioning from http to https. After reading some resources from online I added this line to the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Now when i try to access the `/wp-admin/` page I get the `xx.xx.com redirected you too many times`. The all of the other pages work, it is only the admin panel that is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happened to me sometimes. Try checking between which pages the redirect occurs here: 
[redirect-checker.org](http://redirect-checker.org)
It will help you understand why it happens

If the problem is about a loop between http://example.com and https://example.com you can try changing homeurl and siteurl to avoid this redirect. You can do this:

- In you SQL in the wp_options table
- Putting `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');` in wp-config.php (check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL))

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming here like me being behind a reverse proxy that handle the SSL stuff, it took me a while but I could find the documentation where it states what has to be done:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

It states to add an if in the wp-config:

```
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain 
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
// so check for https existence
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

As I don't like to touch the config (mostly because I forget I touched it) I tried to find a more elegant way of doing it:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/

I have tried with this plugin and it works.

Comment: Needed this for DreamHost, very useful. Thanks